# Android MediaPlayer and playing .pls files

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, internet-radio

I understand that the Android MediaPlayer cannot handle .pls files, but I am trying to create a streaming radio app and the .pls URL is all I have access to. Is there any way to make this work, or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 2):

Just read the .pls files and get all the URLs there. And thats what you have to use since .pls is just a playlist. Once you have all the URLS, you can already use mediaplayer.